# Java Annotation parameter? What is it called

Tags: java, annotations

Java Annotations can have a parameter like here:

```
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
```

Can someone tell me what this content which is in brackets is called?

I'm sure it has a name but i just can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're called elements. They can be named or unnamed. In this case, `value` is an element and its value is `RUNTIME` which is just an enum literal.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/basics.html.